# How to sort date columns by date instead of alphabetically when connecting to SSAS Tabular model?

Tags: sql, excel, ssas, pivot-table, tabular

I've got an SSAS tabular model with a column that hold date values. The SQL column is of `date` type. On the SSAS side, the column data type is `Date`. However, when connecting to the model from Excel, the date comes across as text and sorts alphabetically.

How can I get Excel to sort the column by date?

Column in SSAS Tabular designer:

[image: SSAS Column]

Column after sorting "A to Z" in Excel:

[image: Excel]

Comment: Seems as if the dates comes as text in Excel. Mostly the reason therefore is a date format, that Excel not recognizes as date value. Will this http://cwebbbi.wordpress.com/2013/03/21/ukus-date-format-bug-in-powerpivot-and-ssas-tabular/ help? I would prefer the date format yyyy-mm-dd. I don't know why this date format is not accepted world wide finally. This would prevent so much data exchange problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get Excel to recognize the dates, but managed to get around it. SSAS returns sorted data, and Excel uses that ordering unless changed to `A to Z` or `Z to A` (which is why dates are sorted correctly initially). So, to display dates in reverse order in Excel, what we need to do is to reverse them in SSAS. This can be achieved by using the `Sort By Column` column property.

[image]

What you have is 3 columns: a reference column that decreases as dates increase, a regular `Date` column, and a `Date Reversed` calculated column that holds the same values as `Date`, but has the reference column set as the `Sort By Column`. On the Excel side, if someone adds the `Date` dimension, it will sort in ascending order, and if they add the `Date Reversed` dimension, it will sort in descending order.

[image: SSAS Columns]
[image: Default]
[image: Sorted]